# Wordpress | Не получается добавить фото с помощью ACF

Tags: wordpress, acf

Был обновлен WP и ACF до последней версии. Затем были попытки восстановить более старую версию WP и ACF, пробовал удалить и переустановить плагин заново, а также отключал все другие плагины, но проблему это не решило.

При нажатии на кнопку "Добавить изображение" (произвольное поле ACF), в консоли выскакивает ошибка:

"Uncaught TypeError: args.parent.find is not a function".

Место возникновения ошибки: acf-input.js.

Я подключил полную версию скрипта, а не минифицированную, чтобы попытаться разобраться в ошибке.

Ошибка возникает потому что значение parent вместо селектора является функцией: http://joxi.ru/L21VXgECRXB5bA?d=1

Версия ACF: 5.8.7
Версия WP: 5.3.2

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить в чем проблема.

Comment: Обновить все плагины до последней версии и сбрось кеш в браузере.

Comment: Кэш сбрасывал, а все остальные плагины вообще отключал.

Comment: На какую версию откатывались?